# How to put variables inside a Json Array function in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm a beginner in Js and have a problem making a little program, I want to put the variables nome, document e Codigo, inside of the JSON array 'registros'

```
var registros = [];
var codigo = 1;
function salvar() {
    var nome = document.getElementById("pNome").innerText;
    var documento = document.getElementById("pDocumento").innerText;
    var registro = [{
        codigo: 0,
        nome: "",
        sexo: ""
    }];
    registro.push(codigo, nome, document);
}
```

Comment: You named your array `registros` but then tried to push into `registro` which is not an array but an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array in JS comes in property/ value structure, and from your code you are assigning the values to a different variable registro instead of registros.

Moreover, the registros variable is never user.
To do this;

1. Create your array variable (registros)
2. Create a function (salvar)
3. Create an object that will hold your values, here nome in object will create a property name "nome" with the value being the value in nome which is document.get ...;

   var obj = { "nome": document.getElementById("pNome").innerText.
4. Then push obj to array, registros

```js
var registros = [];
var codigo = 1;
function salvar() {
    var nome = document.getElementById("pNome").innerText;
    var documento = document.getElementById("pDocumento").innerText;
    var obj = { nome, documento, caodigo}

    registros.push(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a little adjustment in the salvar() function.
First, you can set each specific value of your "registro" var like this:

```
var registro = [{
    codigo: codigo, //value = 1
    nome: nome, //value = the innerText of document.getElementById("pNome")
    sexo: ""
}];
```

Then, you use the push() function to insert "registro" into your "registros" array. Here is the full updated code:

```
var registros = [];
var codigo = 1;
function salvar() {
    var nome = document.getElementById("pNome").innerText;
    var documento = document.getElementById("pDocumento").innerText;
    var registro = [{
        codigo: codigo,
        nome: nome,
        sexo: ""
    }];
    registros.push(registro);
}
```